# Reading big matrix of integers fast

Tags: r, io

I am trying to read a big table (around 500000 x 1000) in **R**.

`read.table` works, but is horribly slow.

`scan` works, too, and is OK speedwise, but I have been unable to change its format to a normal data.frame or matrix.

I do not know the number of rows in the table in advance (I can find the number of columns by `template_line <- read.table(nrow=1,file=my_file)`). It needs to be compatible with **R** 2.15 - so it seem `fread` is out of the question.

So the question is either: How do I convert the output from:

```
my_matrix <- scan(file=my_file,what=template_line);
```

to a data.frame or matrix (fast)?

Or: how do I read a table of integers fast in **R** if I do not know the size?

Comment: If `fread` is out, what about `sqldf`? Also, what is the problem you have with the output of `scan`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I need to be able to access `my_matrix[1,2]`, and that does not work given the code above.

Comment: eh? Why is `fread` out? Current CRAN `data.table` is `1.8.10` which states: **`Depends: R (≥ 2.12.0)`**

Comment: try adding `colClasses = "integer"` to your `read.table` call.

Comment: @SimonO101 You seem to be right, and that is much preferable. Can I have data.table::fread read a .gz file?

Comment: Sorry but why would `data.table::fread` be excluded because of `R.2.15.x` ?? I was using it every day when on `2.15.2`

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
num_cols <- 5
my_matrix <- matrix(scan(file=my_file, what=template_line), ncol=num_cols, byrow=TRUE)
```